# Detect parent component of child in current view at Angular 5/6?

Tags: angular6, angular5

I want to get parent component of child component in current view from .ts file in Angular. After I searched a lot , I could not find. I think easiest things can not be found in ANgular so  I am really suprised why it is so popular. Anyway , let me tell what I do.

Think that in parent component 1 and 2 html pages, I use selector directive of child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',

})
export class ChildComponent{
  ngOnInit() {
         //How to write determining code for which parent is active now?
          ////ParentComponent1 or ParentComponent2  ?    


   }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component1',

})
export class ParentComponent1{

}


@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component2',

})
export class Parentomponent2{

}
```

**//How to write determining code for which parent is active now?
              ////ParentComponent1 or ParentComponent2  ?**

Comment: In general, I'd suggest to avoid depending on parent components. Components are intended to be re-usable pieces of code and should (in most cases) not know about their parents. If you need information from your parent you can use a service (and inject this service in parent and child - now you can share data) or if parent is part of routing, check `ActivatedRoute` or pass parent as property of child. You could add why you need access to parent, this would allow people to suggest solutions.

Comment: Good answer thanks. so I only control  url param to get rid of this problem. I think this will be better option.